# how to get a service context from an activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, service, android-context

I need to get a service context from an activity because I am creating an alarm in the service and I would like to delete it in the activity so will have to use same context can I save the context of this service in a `sharedpreferences` as a string but then how can I transform this string as a context?

My alarm code is:

```
 Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimeAlarm.class);            
           //add the notification body to the intent:
           intentAlarm.putExtra("Notif_body", Notif_Body);             
           // create the object
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
           //set the alarm for particular time
           alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+60*1000, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),1,intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

how I am deleting it?

```
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TimeAlarm.class);
            PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),1,i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);               
            alarmManager.cancel(displayIntent);
```

why that's not working?

Comment: you don't have to use the same context. Just use the Activity context and all will work fine.

Comment: or, use the application context in both cases.

Comment: ok will use the application context in both cases because I think that the same context is needed because I couldn't delete the alarm when I used another context will try that thanks.

Comment: i think you are looking for `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: I'm sorry your comments are so useful but not able to mark them..

Answer (score 0):

> hi I need to get a service context from an activity

No, you do not.

> so will have to use same context

No, you do not.

> can I save the context of this service in a sharedpreferences as a string

No, you cannot.

> I think that the same context is needed

No, you do not.

> I couldn't delete the alarm when I used another context

Then there is something else wrong with your code. You can cancel alarms using a completely different *process*, let alone a different `Context`.

Comment: please check the code that I've added I have no idea why that's not working.

Comment: @user2849412: Try getting rid of `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` for the `PendingIntent` that you are using in `cancel()`. Beyond that, also use **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`** to see if you perhaps have *another* alarm scheduled, perhaps from some previous run of your app. You can wipe out your alarms by uninstalling and reinstalling your app, or via Force Stop in Settings.

Comment: @user2849412: Do you have two classes named `TimeAlarm`?

Comment: no sure not I even added intentAlarm.putExtra("Notif_body", ""); to it because I thought it's the cause but still couldn't delete it..